# What are the strings for missing Edit2D events?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Below you will find an excerpt from the utodesk documentation for the v7 viewer found [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/advanced_options/edit2d-setup/).
There are two event listeners im trying to reference. There is, however, no existing event strings for these. **Autodesk.Edit2D.SELECTION_CHANGED** and **Autodesk.Edit2D.SELECTION_HOVER_CHANGED** won't work in my console after the extension is loaded (they just return undefined. Is there a way to find the list of event strings for this extension?

> **Synchronizing selection**

> You can also synchronize selection with Edit2D for certain items in your UI using >edit2d.context.selection.
> One way to do this is to register a handler. The handler ensures the application is notified if >selection changes.
> In the following example, we’ve set the handler to listen for mouse clicks.

> ```
> // Register your handler
> ctx.selection.addEventListener(Autodesk.Edit2D.SELECTION_CHANGED, onSelectionChanged);
> ```
>
> Similarly, you can set the handler to synchronize mouse hovering:
>
> ```
> // Update UI state on hover changes
> ctx.selection.addEventListener(Autodesk.Edit2D.SELECTION_HOVER_CHANGED, onHoverChanged);
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the event string for the two event under 'Autodesk.Edit2D.Selection.Events' like below code.

```
// Register your handler
ctx.selection.addEventListener(Autodesk.Edit2D.Selection.Events.SELECTION_CHANGED, onSelectionChanged);

// Update UI state on hover changes
ctx.selection.addEventListener(Autodesk.Edit2D.Selection.Events.SELECTION_HOVER_CHANGED, onHoverChanged);
```

Comment: thanks. they really need to update their documentation.